# Como colocar uma tag h3 e p dentro de uma classe

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Como faço para colocar uma tag `h3` e uma `p` na mesma imagem, porém quero colocar a tag `p` abaixo como um `footer`e a `h3`no topo da imagem,quando passar o mouse na imagem o `hover` trás as duas tags juntas.

CSS:

```
  position:relative;
  height:170px;
  width:100%;
  margin: -90px 100px 110px -0px;
  border:5px solid #E6E6FA;
  box-shadow:4px 4px 8px black;
}

#hColunas{
  font-family:"Lucida Console";
  font-size:20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  color:#fff;
  width:100%;
  height:170px;
  top:-20px;
  opacity:0;
}
#hColunas:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
#pColunas{
  font-family:"Lucida Console";
  font-size:15px;
  position:absolute;
  top:120px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  width:100%;
  opacity:0;
}
#hColunas:p{
  top:120px;
}
#pColunas:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="alimages">
  <div class="colunasDeImages">
    <a href="http://www.itapemapark.com.br/" target="_blank"><img src="backgrounds/nyaqua1.jpg" width="220px" height="170px"></a>

    <h3 id="hColunas">Confira nossas instalações</h3>
    <p id="pColunas">Uma nova maneira de curtir o verão</p>
  </div>

  <div class="colunasDeImages">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="backgrounds/nyaqua2.jpg"  width="220px" height="170px"></a>
    <h3 id="hColunas">Confira nossas trilhas e passeios</h3>
    <p id="pColunas">Uma nova maneira de curtir o verão</p>
   </div>
   <div class="colunasDeImages">
     <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="backgrounds/nyaqua3.jpg" width="220px" height="170px"></a>
     <h3 id="hColunas">Confira nosso local para refeições</h3>
     <p id="pColunas">Uma nova maneira de curtir o verão</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: O que vc quer dizer como Juntas? Vc quer que o H3 esteja em uma linha e o P na linha de baixo, mas quando vc passar o Mouse na imagem o H3 e o P fiquem na mesma linha é isso? Vc teria alguma imagem do layout de como vc quer que fique? Seu código está meio confuso.

Comment: No caso,eu tenho uma imagem que ao passar o mouse em cima dela,tenho uma mascara criada com hover que tem um H3 e um P,só que quero que o P fique bem embaixo da imagem como um footer da imagem, e a H3 como um cabeçalho,quero saber se é com padding que faço essa correção na minha imagem.

Comment: Agora acho que entendi. O padding não é a melhor opção para isso, pois com ele vc vai depender de um valor fixo, e se algum das suas imagens for maior o P não vai ficar no logar desejado. Como vc tem dois elementos o H3 e o P vc pode usar position:absolute, e top:0 no H3 e no P vc poloca bottom:0. Vou fazer um exemplo simples e posto na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Como citado pelo colega, não use id, use class. O id deve ser único entre todos os elementos, então seu HTML estaria errado na verdade.

Você consegue usar direto assim como fez seu HTML, com a imagem, o h3 e o p dentro de um div container, porém para facilitar o posicionamento dos textos, acho que fica mais interessante com um div extra para cada parte do texto, cima e baixo. Veja os dois no exemplo:

```css
.img-with-overlay {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.img-with-overlay img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto auto;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.img-with-overlay .top, .img-with-overlay .bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
  color: #eee;
  transition: all;
  transition-duration: 0.2s
}
.img-with-overlay .top {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 2.3em;
}
.img-with-overlay .bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
.img-with-overlay:hover .top, .img-with-overlay:hover .bottom {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-with-overlay">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/400" />
  <div class="top">
    <h3>Gato 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Com um div ao redor de cada texto, facilita os posicionamentos</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="img-with-overlay">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/400" />
  <h3 class="top">Gato 2</h3>
  <p class="bottom">Direto só com as tags</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser aplicar um estilo a vários elementos use classes pois id se refere a um e apenas um elemento.

obs: mudei `h3` para `span` para que os textos fiquem compatíveis com o tamanho das imagens nessa apresentação.

A ideia principal é como fazer aparecer os dois textos no over.

```css
        .alimages {
            margin:50px 0 0 0;
            width:250px;
            height:240px;
             text-align:center;
        }

        .image {
            position:relative;
            margin:40px 0 0 40px;
        }
        
        .overlay, .overlayp  {
            display:none;
        }
        
        .image:hover .overlay {
            width:250px;
            height:240px;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
            position:absolute;
            top:-22px;
            left:-15px;
            display:inline-block;
        }

        .image:hover .overlayp {
            width:250px;
            height:240px;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
            position:absolute;
            top:160px;
            left:-15px;
            display:inline-block;
        }

        .hColunas {
            font-family:"Arial black";
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
            color:#fff;
        }

        .pColunas{
            font-family:"Arial";
            font-size: 14px;
            background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
            color:#fff;
        }
```

```html
<div class="alimages">
          <div class="image">
             <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/200" width="220px" height="170px"/>
              <div class="overlay">
              <span class="hColunas">Confira nossas instalações</span>
              </div>
              <div class="overlayp">
              <p class="pColunas">Uma nova maneira de curtir o verão</p>
              </div>
          </div> 
          <div class="image">
              <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/200" width="220px" height="170px"/>
              <div class="overlay">
              <span class="hColunas">Confira nossas trilhas e passeios</span>
              </div>
              <div class="overlayp">
              <p class="pColunas">Uma nova maneira de curtir o verão</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="image">
              <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/200" width="220px" height="170px"/>
              <div class="overlay">
              <span class="hColunas">Confira nosso local para refeições</span>
              </div>
              <div class="overlayp">
              <p class="pColunas">Uma nova maneira de curtir o verão</p>
              </div>
          </div>
</div>
```